# Jackson JSON to Java mapping for same attrubute with different data type

Tags: json, mapping, jackson

I have a JSON object which I don't have control of and want to map it to a Java object which is pre-created.
There is one attribute in the JSON object which can be a URL or it could be a JSONArray.

```
Class SomeClass {

    private URL items;

    public URL getURL() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setURL(URL url) {
        this.items = url;
    }
}
```

Below is the JSON:

Case A:

```
{
...
    items: http://someurl.abc.com/linktoitems,
...
}
```

OR

Case B

```
{
...
    items: [
            { "id": id1, "name": name1 },
            { "id": id2, "name": name2 }
           ]
...
}
```

If i create the POJO to map for Case A, Case B fails and vice versa. In short, is there a way to map the JSON attribute to the POJO field with different data types? In that case I will create two separate fields in the POJO named,

```
private URL itemLink;
private Item[] itemList;
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exact details, but if what you are asking is if it is possible to map either JSON String or JSON array into a Java property, yes this can be done.

Obvious way would be to define a custom deserializer which handles both kinds of JSON input.
But it is also possible to define Java type in such a way that it can be constructed both by setting properties (which works from JSON Object) and have a single-String-arg constructor or static single-String-arg factory method marked with @JsonCreator.

Yet another possibility is to use an intermediate type that can deserialized from any JSON: both java.lang.Object and JsonNode ("JSON tree") instances can be created from any JSON. From this value you would need to do manual conversion; most likely in setter, like so:

```
public void setItems(JsonNode treeRoot) { .... }
```

What will not work, however, is defining two properties with the same name.

One thing I don't quite follow is how you would convert from List to URL though. So maybe you actually do need two separate internal fields; and setter would just assign to one of those (and getter would return value of just one).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am manually identifying the data type of the key and assigning the value to appropriate object (URL or List)